# sqlcmd truncates long line query. How to run query with line length more than 5000?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I have datatable with large number of columns.
When I edit the datatable in management studio, i can generate change script.
But when i run the script in sqlcmd, it fails on the insert command. The command has list of all columns in single line, and the length of the line is 5417. So, sqlcmd truncates the line on 5000 chars, and the query fails.
How can I avoid the 5000 chars limitation?

Steps to reproduce the issue:
1) run sqlcmd;
2) paste the following lines:

```
INSERT INTO Tmp_Table1 (ExampleColumnNo1, ExampleColumnNo2, ExampleColumnNo3, ExampleColumnNo4, ExampleColumnNo5, ExampleColumnNo6, ExampleColumnNo7, ExampleColumnNo8, ExampleColumnNo9, ExampleColumnNo10, ExampleColumnNo11, ExampleColumnNo12, ExampleColumnNo13, ExampleColumnNo14, ExampleColumnNo15, ExampleColumnNo16, ExampleColumnNo17, ExampleColumnNo18, ExampleColumnNo19, ExampleColumnNo20, ExampleColumnNo21, ExampleColumnNo22, ExampleColumnNo23, ExampleColumnNo24, ExampleColumnNo25, ExampleColumnNo26, ExampleColumnNo27, ExampleColumnNo28, ExampleColumnNo29, ExampleColumnNo30, ExampleColumnNo31, ExampleColumnNo32, ExampleColumnNo33, ExampleColumnNo34, ExampleColumnNo35, ExampleColumnNo36, ExampleColumnNo37, ExampleColumnNo38, ExampleColumnNo39, ExampleColumnNo40, ExampleColumnNo41, ExampleColumnNo42, ExampleColumnNo43, ExampleColumnNo44, ExampleColumnNo45, ExampleColumnNo46, ExampleColumnNo47, ExampleColumnNo48, ExampleColumnNo49, ExampleColumnNo50, ExampleColumnNo51, ExampleColumnNo52, ExampleColumnNo53, ExampleColumnNo54, ExampleColumnNo55, ExampleColumnNo56, ExampleColumnNo57, ExampleColumnNo58, ExampleColumnNo59, ExampleColumnNo60, ExampleColumnNo61, ExampleColumnNo62, ExampleColumnNo63, ExampleColumnNo64, ExampleColumnNo65, ExampleColumnNo66, ExampleColumnNo67, ExampleColumnNo68, ExampleColumnNo69, ExampleColumnNo70, ExampleColumnNo71, ExampleColumnNo72, ExampleColumnNo73, ExampleColumnNo74, ExampleColumnNo75, ExampleColumnNo76, ExampleColumnNo77, ExampleColumnNo78, ExampleColumnNo79, ExampleColumnNo80, ExampleColumnNo81, ExampleColumnNo82, ExampleColumnNo83, ExampleColumnNo84, ExampleColumnNo85, ExampleColumnNo86, ExampleColumnNo87, ExampleColumnNo88, ExampleColumnNo89, ExampleColumnNo90, ExampleColumnNo91, ExampleColumnNo92, ExampleColumnNo93, ExampleColumnNo94, ExampleColumnNo95, ExampleColumnNo96, ExampleColumnNo97, ExampleColumnNo98, ExampleColumnNo99, ExampleColumnNo100, ExampleColumnNo101, ExampleColumnNo102, ExampleColumnNo103, ExampleColumnNo104, ExampleColumnNo105, ExampleColumnNo106, ExampleColumnNo107, ExampleColumnNo108, ExampleColumnNo109, ExampleColumnNo110, ExampleColumnNo111, ExampleColumnNo112, ExampleColumnNo113, ExampleColumnNo114, ExampleColumnNo115, ExampleColumnNo116, ExampleColumnNo117, ExampleColumnNo118, ExampleColumnNo119, ExampleColumnNo120, ExampleColumnNo121, ExampleColumnNo122, ExampleColumnNo123, ExampleColumnNo124, ExampleColumnNo125, ExampleColumnNo126, ExampleColumnNo127, ExampleColumnNo128, ExampleColumnNo129, ExampleColumnNo130, ExampleColumnNo131, ExampleColumnNo132, ExampleColumnNo133, ExampleColumnNo134, ExampleColumnNo135, ExampleColumnNo136, ExampleColumnNo137, ExampleColumnNo138, ExampleColumnNo139, ExampleColumnNo140, ExampleColumnNo141, ExampleColumnNo142, ExampleColumnNo143, ExampleColumnNo144, ExampleColumnNo145, ExampleColumnNo146, ExampleColumnNo147, ExampleColumnNo148, ExampleColumnNo149, ExampleColumnNo150, ExampleColumnNo151, ExampleColumnNo152, ExampleColumnNo153, ExampleColumnNo154, ExampleColumnNo155, ExampleColumnNo156, ExampleColumnNo157, ExampleColumnNo158, ExampleColumnNo159, ExampleColumnNo160, ExampleColumnNo161, ExampleColumnNo162, ExampleColumnNo163, ExampleColumnNo164, ExampleColumnNo165, ExampleColumnNo166, ExampleColumnNo167, ExampleColumnNo168, ExampleColumnNo169, ExampleColumnNo170, ExampleColumnNo171, ExampleColumnNo172, ExampleColumnNo173, ExampleColumnNo174, ExampleColumnNo175, ExampleColumnNo176, ExampleColumnNo177, ExampleColumnNo178, ExampleColumnNo179, ExampleColumnNo180, ExampleColumnNo181, ExampleColumnNo182, ExampleColumnNo183, ExampleColumnNo184, ExampleColumnNo185, ExampleColumnNo186, ExampleColumnNo187, ExampleColumnNo188, ExampleColumnNo189, ExampleColumnNo190, ExampleColumnNo191, ExampleColumnNo192, ExampleColumnNo193, ExampleColumnNo194, ExampleColumnNo195, ExampleColumnNo196, ExampleColumnNo197, ExampleColumnNo198, ExampleColumnNo199, ExampleColumnNo200, ExampleColumnNo201, ExampleColumnNo202, ExampleColumnNo203, ExampleColumnNo204, ExampleColumnNo205, ExampleColumnNo206, ExampleColumnNo207, ExampleColumnNo208, ExampleColumnNo209, ExampleColumnNo210, ExampleColumnNo211, ExampleColumnNo212, ExampleColumnNo213, ExampleColumnNo214, ExampleColumnNo215, ExampleColumnNo216, ExampleColumnNo217, ExampleColumnNo218, ExampleColumnNo219, ExampleColumnNo220, ExampleColumnNo221, ExampleColumnNo222, ExampleColumnNo223, ExampleColumnNo224, ExampleColumnNo225, ExampleColumnNo226, ExampleColumnNo227, ExampleColumnNo228, ExampleColumnNo229, ExampleColumnNo230, ExampleColumnNo231, ExampleColumnNo232, ExampleColumnNo233, ExampleColumnNo234, ExampleColumnNo235, ExampleColumnNo236, ExampleColumnNo237, ExampleColumnNo238, ExampleColumnNo239, ExampleColumnNo240, ExampleColumnNo241, ExampleColumnNo242, ExampleColumnNo243, ExampleColumnNo244, ExampleColumnNo245, ExampleColumnNo246, ExampleColumnNo247, ExampleColumnNo248, ExampleColumnNo249, ExampleColumnNo250, ExampleColumnNo251, ExampleColumnNo252, ExampleColumnNo253, ExampleColumnNo254, ExampleColumnNo255, ExampleColumnNo256, ExampleColumnNo257, ExampleColumnNo258, ExampleColumnNo259, ExampleColumnNo260, ExampleColumnNo261, ExampleColumnNo262, ExampleColumnNo263, ExampleColumnNo264, ExampleColumnNo265, ExampleColumnNo266, ExampleColumnNo267, ExampleColumnNo268, ExampleColumnNo269, ExampleColumnNo270, ExampleColumnNo271, ExampleColumnNo272, ExampleColumnNo273, ExampleColumnNo274, ExampleColumnNo275, ExampleColumnNo276, ExampleColumnNo277, ExampleColumnNo278, ExampleColumnNo279, ExampleColumnNo280, ExampleColumnNo281, ExampleColumnNo282, ExampleColumnNo283, ExampleColumnNo284, ExampleColumnNo285, ExampleColumnNo286, ExampleColumnNo287, ExampleColumnNo288, ExampleColumnNo289, ExampleColumnNo290, ExampleColumnNo291, ExampleColumnNo292, ExampleColumnNo293, ExampleColumnNo294, ExampleColumnNo295, ExampleColumnNo296, ExampleColumnNo297, ExampleColumnNo298, ExampleColumnNo299, ExampleColumnNo300)
SELECT ExampleColumnNo1, ExampleColumnNo2, ExampleColumnNo3, ExampleColumnNo4, ExampleColumnNo5, ExampleColumnNo6, ExampleColumnNo7, ExampleColumnNo8, ExampleColumnNo9, ExampleColumnNo10, ExampleColumnNo11, ExampleColumnNo12, ExampleColumnNo13, ExampleColumnNo14, ExampleColumnNo15, ExampleColumnNo16, ExampleColumnNo17, ExampleColumnNo18, ExampleColumnNo19, ExampleColumnNo20, ExampleColumnNo21, ExampleColumnNo22, ExampleColumnNo23, ExampleColumnNo24, ExampleColumnNo25, ExampleColumnNo26, ExampleColumnNo27, ExampleColumnNo28, ExampleColumnNo29, ExampleColumnNo30, ExampleColumnNo31, ExampleColumnNo32, ExampleColumnNo33, ExampleColumnNo34, ExampleColumnNo35, ExampleColumnNo36, ExampleColumnNo37, ExampleColumnNo38, ExampleColumnNo39, ExampleColumnNo40, ExampleColumnNo41, ExampleColumnNo42, ExampleColumnNo43, ExampleColumnNo44, ExampleColumnNo45, ExampleColumnNo46, ExampleColumnNo47, ExampleColumnNo48, ExampleColumnNo49, ExampleColumnNo50, ExampleColumnNo51, ExampleColumnNo52, ExampleColumnNo53, ExampleColumnNo54, ExampleColumnNo55, ExampleColumnNo56, ExampleColumnNo57, ExampleColumnNo58, ExampleColumnNo59, ExampleColumnNo60, ExampleColumnNo61, ExampleColumnNo62, ExampleColumnNo63, ExampleColumnNo64, ExampleColumnNo65, ExampleColumnNo66, ExampleColumnNo67, ExampleColumnNo68, ExampleColumnNo69, ExampleColumnNo70, ExampleColumnNo71, ExampleColumnNo72, ExampleColumnNo73, ExampleColumnNo74, ExampleColumnNo75, ExampleColumnNo76, ExampleColumnNo77, ExampleColumnNo78, ExampleColumnNo79, ExampleColumnNo80, ExampleColumnNo81, ExampleColumnNo82, ExampleColumnNo83, ExampleColumnNo84, ExampleColumnNo85, ExampleColumnNo86, ExampleColumnNo87, ExampleColumnNo88, ExampleColumnNo89, ExampleColumnNo90, ExampleColumnNo91, ExampleColumnNo92, ExampleColumnNo93, ExampleColumnNo94, ExampleColumnNo95, ExampleColumnNo96, ExampleColumnNo97, ExampleColumnNo98, ExampleColumnNo99, ExampleColumnNo100, ExampleColumnNo101, ExampleColumnNo102, ExampleColumnNo103, ExampleColumnNo104, ExampleColumnNo105, ExampleColumnNo106, ExampleColumnNo107, ExampleColumnNo108, ExampleColumnNo109, ExampleColumnNo110, ExampleColumnNo111, ExampleColumnNo112, ExampleColumnNo113, ExampleColumnNo114, ExampleColumnNo115, ExampleColumnNo116, ExampleColumnNo117, ExampleColumnNo118, ExampleColumnNo119, ExampleColumnNo120, ExampleColumnNo121, ExampleColumnNo122, ExampleColumnNo123, ExampleColumnNo124, ExampleColumnNo125, ExampleColumnNo126, ExampleColumnNo127, ExampleColumnNo128, ExampleColumnNo129, ExampleColumnNo130, ExampleColumnNo131, ExampleColumnNo132, ExampleColumnNo133, ExampleColumnNo134, ExampleColumnNo135, ExampleColumnNo136, ExampleColumnNo137, ExampleColumnNo138, ExampleColumnNo139, ExampleColumnNo140, ExampleColumnNo141, ExampleColumnNo142, ExampleColumnNo143, ExampleColumnNo144, ExampleColumnNo145, ExampleColumnNo146, ExampleColumnNo147, ExampleColumnNo148, ExampleColumnNo149, ExampleColumnNo150, ExampleColumnNo151, ExampleColumnNo152, ExampleColumnNo153, ExampleColumnNo154, ExampleColumnNo155, ExampleColumnNo156, ExampleColumnNo157, ExampleColumnNo158, ExampleColumnNo159, ExampleColumnNo160, ExampleColumnNo161, ExampleColumnNo162, ExampleColumnNo163, ExampleColumnNo164, ExampleColumnNo165, ExampleColumnNo166, ExampleColumnNo167, ExampleColumnNo168, ExampleColumnNo169, ExampleColumnNo170, ExampleColumnNo171, ExampleColumnNo172, ExampleColumnNo173, ExampleColumnNo174, ExampleColumnNo175, ExampleColumnNo176, ExampleColumnNo177, ExampleColumnNo178, ExampleColumnNo179, ExampleColumnNo180, ExampleColumnNo181, ExampleColumnNo182, ExampleColumnNo183, ExampleColumnNo184, ExampleColumnNo185, ExampleColumnNo186, ExampleColumnNo187, ExampleColumnNo188, ExampleColumnNo189, ExampleColumnNo190, ExampleColumnNo191, ExampleColumnNo192, ExampleColumnNo193, ExampleColumnNo194, ExampleColumnNo195, ExampleColumnNo196, ExampleColumnNo197, ExampleColumnNo198, ExampleColumnNo199, ExampleColumnNo200, ExampleColumnNo201, ExampleColumnNo202, ExampleColumnNo203, ExampleColumnNo204, ExampleColumnNo205, ExampleColumnNo206, ExampleColumnNo207, ExampleColumnNo208, ExampleColumnNo209, ExampleColumnNo210, ExampleColumnNo211, ExampleColumnNo212, ExampleColumnNo213, ExampleColumnNo214, ExampleColumnNo215, ExampleColumnNo216, ExampleColumnNo217, ExampleColumnNo218, ExampleColumnNo219, ExampleColumnNo220, ExampleColumnNo221, ExampleColumnNo222, ExampleColumnNo223, ExampleColumnNo224, ExampleColumnNo225, ExampleColumnNo226, ExampleColumnNo227, ExampleColumnNo228, ExampleColumnNo229, ExampleColumnNo230, ExampleColumnNo231, ExampleColumnNo232, ExampleColumnNo233, ExampleColumnNo234, ExampleColumnNo235, ExampleColumnNo236, ExampleColumnNo237, ExampleColumnNo238, ExampleColumnNo239, ExampleColumnNo240, ExampleColumnNo241, ExampleColumnNo242, ExampleColumnNo243, ExampleColumnNo244, ExampleColumnNo245, ExampleColumnNo246, ExampleColumnNo247, ExampleColumnNo248, ExampleColumnNo249, ExampleColumnNo250, ExampleColumnNo251, ExampleColumnNo252, ExampleColumnNo253, ExampleColumnNo254, ExampleColumnNo255, ExampleColumnNo256, ExampleColumnNo257, ExampleColumnNo258, ExampleColumnNo259, ExampleColumnNo260, ExampleColumnNo261, ExampleColumnNo262, ExampleColumnNo263, ExampleColumnNo264, ExampleColumnNo265, ExampleColumnNo266, ExampleColumnNo267, ExampleColumnNo268, ExampleColumnNo269, ExampleColumnNo270, ExampleColumnNo271, ExampleColumnNo272, ExampleColumnNo273, ExampleColumnNo274, ExampleColumnNo275, ExampleColumnNo276, ExampleColumnNo277, ExampleColumnNo278, ExampleColumnNo279, ExampleColumnNo280, ExampleColumnNo281, ExampleColumnNo282, ExampleColumnNo283, ExampleColumnNo284, ExampleColumnNo285, ExampleColumnNo286, ExampleColumnNo287, ExampleColumnNo288, ExampleColumnNo289, ExampleColumnNo290, ExampleColumnNo291, ExampleColumnNo292, ExampleColumnNo293, ExampleColumnNo294, ExampleColumnNo295, ExampleColumnNo296, ExampleColumnNo297, ExampleColumnNo298, ExampleColumnNo299, ExampleColumnNo300 FROM dbo.dbc_Table1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got this working by moving query into a file and feeding the tool with `-i filename.sql` parameters. Not ideal, but works.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would first try editing the SQL script to simply add a return
   before (or after) the "VALUES" keyword. You can actually put any of
   the parts of the INSERT statement on different lines:

   ```
   INSERT INTO  
   TableName (Column1,  
   Column2)  
   VALUES (  
   N'some text',  
   55 )
   ```
2. Or, if SQLCMD doesn't care about line breaks but instead it cares
   about the actual SQL statement being executed, then assuming you are
   inserting all columns that are insertable (meaning: no IDENTITY or
   TIMESTAMP/ROWVERSION fields as you generally do not insert into
   IDENTITY and cannot insert into TIMESTAMP/ROWVERSION) and that the
   values in the VALUES clause are in the same order that SQL Server
   has them listed in (which I would assume would be the case if SSMS
   generated the INSERT statement), then you can remove the field list
   from the INSERT statement:

   ```
   INSERT INTO TableName VALUES (N'some text', 55)
   ```

   This syntax is generally not preferred as any change in the table
   schema (i.e. add / remove columns) would break the INSERT statement, but
   for a one-time script it is fine.
3. If that doesn't help, you can usually "continue" a string onto the next
   line by putting a back-slash "\" where you want the end of the line to
   be and making sure to continue on the next line starting in the first
   character position.  For example:

   ```
   DECLARE @InsertTest TABLE (TextCol NVARCHAR(50), IntCol INT)

   INSERT INTO @InsertTest (TextCol, IntCol) VALUES (N'This is a looooooooooo\  
   ooooooooong string', 55)  

   SELECT * FROM @InsertTest
   ```

Comment: Thank you for reply!
I would add 4th solution, it's simplest in my case:
4. Just split the long line on smaller lines.
But I would not like to modify auto-generated script, and looking for the solution to force sqlcmd to accept lines more than 5000 chars.

Comment: @RomanO, I think your suggestion for #4 is the same as my #1. I test ed with your 2 long lines and the limit appears to be 4998 characters but suggestion #1 did work. It also appears to be an internal SQLCMD limitation and I don't see any way around that. I also don't think you need to worry about scripts generated from SSMS. Sometimes they need to be updated. Also, it makes sense to let SSMS generate the syntax of an INSERT statement with so many fields, but I wouldn't get in the habt of using SSMS to do DML statements; SSMS is not meant to be a scripting tool.

Comment: and what tool you can recommend to generate DML statements?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why is the data moving from one system to another, how often, is it automated, etc?  Maybe there is a better approach than exporting and importing. Depending on your needs it might be better to directly transfer the data via LinkedServer, SSIS, or some other means. There are many options. Does the data need to be in the form of an INSERT statement? Regardless, this is likely not the best forum for this discussion. You can go to my profile and contact me directly if you like. But to help others with the same question (as asked), my suggestion #1 works, correct?

Comment: Yes, it works as workaround, but it does not fix sqlcmd problem.
Can't see contact details in your profile, but it relates to the question, so other people using Management Studio and sqlcmd together can avoid the problem described above.
I develop application and there is database used by the application. Over development process, I change datatables structure and use Design command in management studio for this. After the changes are made, I click "Generate Change Script", and store the script in upgrade .sql file. After task is completed, i publish the changes on test server.

Comment: I use the ugrade script in sqlcmd. Why I use sqlcmd? Because it has option -b stopping execution when an error occurs.

Comment: There probably is no true fix for the SQLCMD line size limit. It appears to be an internal and non-configurable limit (I even checked for possible registry settings). So I don't see any way around editing generated scripts if they produce lines greater than 4998 characters. That is pretty much all that can be said about this particular question. Now, how to best script DML and DDL changes is another question. And I do agree that the "-b" flag is a necessity :).

Comment: For scripting of DML and DDL changes, you can look at www.ssmstoolspack.com and www.red-gate.com/ for "sql-compare". And there might be other options. A package that I wrote and sell (www.sqlsharp.com) can also programatically generate DML statements but not based on what has changed. Using the Designer to generate scripts is not a preferred method of doing this; the SQL it generates is not always ideal or even correct (SQL Jobs are sometimes minorly wrong). I write scripts by hand, and if I need SSMS to generate something I only use it as a starting point and always edit it to be re-runnable.